# Show dynamic result in a UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uipopovercontroller

I can't set data inside the viewController "searchController" managed by a UIPopoverController:
in viewDidLoad i have:

```
searchController = [[PopOverSearchController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PopOverSearchController" bundle:nil];

popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:searchController];
```

I do a method for call this popover that work fine:

```
if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
} else {


    searchController.data = data;
    [searchController.tableResult reloadData];

    CGRect popRect = CGRectMake(self.searchBar.frame.origin.x,
                                self.searchBar.frame.origin.y +15,
                                self.searchBar.frame.size.width,
                                self.searchBar.frame.size.height);
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popRect
                                       inView:self.view
                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                     animated:YES];
}
```

[searchController.tableResult reloadData]; was not called: the popup appear (above the search bar )but with an empty table

Comment: Make sure you have declared `UITableViewDataSource` protocol in the header of your `searchController` and `delegate` property of that table view is set properly. Please also make sure the variable `data` actually has some value in it. It would be helpful if you can post some code from your `searchController`